# Create duplicate of list item in another list including ALL column content

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, workflow, item

I've seen other posts here discussing similar questions, but I believe this one may be unique.  Here's what I've got -

In SharePoint 2013, I'm trying to create a workflow that runs whenever a new item is created in LIST A.   This workflow would create a new item in LIST B, with all column content copied over as well.

I've successfully created a workflow that will create a new item in LIST B when an item is created in LIST A.  However, these items are BLANK.  None of the column content shows up.

Am I skipping a step?

(BTW, I'm using Nintex Workflow, but I can follow just about anything written for SPD as well)

Answer (score 1):

I test your scenario in SharePoint Designer workflow, I create a workflow which create an item in list B with all columns' value in list A, when an item created in list A.

All the columns' value are copied in the list B newly items.

I set the workflow as below:

[image]

The result as below:

[image]

[image]

Whether the column type is the same between list A and list B?

Comment: I eventually saw where I hadn't listed the item fields.  Of course, it looks a bit different in Nintex Workflow, but the concept and structure are still the same.  Your post provided a reminder of this.  Thank you.